# Pass variable to Simple_Form custom input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, form-for

I'm trying to record multiple records using a simple_form custom input.  My input is:

```
class InlinedateInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    "#{@builder.text_field("startmonth", input_html_options)}".html_safe + "/" +    "#  
    {@builder.text_field("startday", input_html_options)}".html_safe + "/" "# 
    {@builder.text_field("startyear", input_html_options)}".html_safe + "To:    " "#
    {@builder.text_field("endmonth", input_html_options)}".html_safe + "/" + "#
    {@builder.text_field("endday", input_html_options)}".html_safe + "/" "#
    {@builder.text_field("endyear", input_html_options)}".html_safe + "Price:" "#
    {@builder.text_field("price", input_html_options)}".html_safe
  end

  #Makes the label target the day input
  def label_target
    "month"
  end
end
```

Basically, the problem is that I have a bunch of different inputs defined in this input.  So if I try to use this method a few times in a form it will only submit the last one.  I need someway to pass a counter variable from my form so that I can have startday_1, startday_2, etc.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass any parameter you want to your custom input through options hash.

For example, you can easily pass custom parameter (counter) to your input:

```rb
= f.input :my_field, :as => :custom_input, :counter => 2
```

and access it into your custom input code:

```rb
class CustomInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  def input
    counter = options[:counter] || -1
    input_html_options[:value] = counter
    super
  end
end
```